# Assure order when using $skip and $limit in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have data like this in my collection:

```
...
{ name: 'ad1cvbc', price: 300 },
{ name: 'tbcvbc3', price: 500 },
{ name: 'yjc5vbc', price: 500 },
{ name: 'at7vvbc', price: 500 },
{ name: 'a86v5bc', price: 500 },
{ name: 'a23dvbc', price: 500 },
{ name: 'adth4bc', price: 500 },
{ name: 'e34bc', price: 700 },
...
```

And I have an aggregate like this:

```
[
    { $match: { ... } },
    { $sort: { price: -1 } },
    { $skip: x },
    { $limit: 20 }
]
```

Where `x` is increased with 20 every single time I wants more data, but the problem is that, because I have multiple `price` with same value( and I have more than 20) sometimes I get the same `document`. How cand I assure that the order is the same and I don't get duplicates when I have many rows with the field for the sort having the same value.

Edit: So if I want to get 3 items each time I may have the following results:

1st call result:

```
{ name: 'ad1cvbc', price: 300 },
{ name: 'tbcvbc3', price: 500 },
{ name: 'yjc5vbc', price: 500 }  // <- this
```

2st call result:

```
{ name: 'a23dvbc', price: 500 },
{ name: 'yjc5vbc', price: 500 }, // <- this
{ name: 'at7vvbc', price: 500 }
```

1 document is repeated because MongoDB doesn't get each time the items in order when the documents has the same value for the sort field.

Comment: did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
[
    { $match: { ... } },
    { $sort: { name:-1, price: -1 } },
    { $skip: x },
    { $limit: x + 20 }
]
```

Comment: I added more details

Comment: I looked at the update. Not sure how to interpret that. You only care for distinct values right ?

Comment: No, I want to get all the documents in different calls but in order and using $skip and $limit will not assure me that the next call I will get the next `x` documents.

Comment: You can add sort by name and price to have a consistent sort across documents.